# VBA - Type mismatch declaring array

Tags: arrays, vba

I'm stuck on a seemingly simple issue.

I'm trying to declare an array like the below in my VBA code, but I always get a type mismatch error.

```
Dim packageRequiredCols As Variant
Set packageRequiredCols = Array("Type", "Package Name", "Supplier Product Name", "Cost Method", _
"Unit Type", "Unit Rate", "Planned Unit Amount", "Flight Start", "Flight End", "Served by")
```

Based on other stackoverflow questions I've tried adding () like:

```
Dim packageRequiredCols() As Variant
```

But this gives a "can't assign to array" error.

Comment: Remove the `Set` keyword.

Comment: Worked great, thank you. Could you quickly explain why `set` is not necessary here?

Comment: You use `Set` to set an object reference (collection, dictionary etc.) but not of `Variant` type. Variants act like value types.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Dim arr

arr = Array("apple","Orange","Grapes")
```